# To support Chinese/Japanese characters what should be the character set declaration in HTML document?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I tried with the following string

```
content=”text/html; charset=utf-8”
```

Though I can experiment myself. I don't know Japanese characters so can't verify browsers displaying it correctly or not.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utf-8 covers most countries all over the world. Though not all of these countries' characters, this encoding suffices civil use.

if you got the Chinese characters right, then i assume your server side job is done.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is right. It can represent any Unicode character, and Unicode has [pretty good coverage](http://unicode.org/charts/) of any character you're likely to want in your document. Everyday Japanese doesn't even scratch the surface of Unicode — heck, the standard even has codepoints for the [Deseret alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deseret_alphabet).